# Is it possible to write lifecycle callbacks in entity repository class rather than in entity?

Tags: symfony, callback, lifecycle

I am curious to know if we can write lifecycle callbacks in an entity repository class rather than in the entity itself?

I am aware that I can write the callback in an abstract class for that my abstract base class has to be annotated as Mapped Superclasses and include the HasLifecycleCallbacks-Annotation

Comment: No but you can register your repository as a doctrine event listener and possibly achieve your goals.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is no, but if you like to write you lifecycle callbacks in separate class you can do it using Entity Listeners like this in Doctrine2.4:

Register your listener:

```
<doctrine-mapping>
    <entity name="MyProject\Entity\User">
        <entity-listeners>
            <entity-listener class="UserListener"/>
        </entity-listeners>
        <!-- .... -->
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

and write your class like this:

```
class UserListener
{
    public function preUpdate(User $user, PreUpdateEventArgs $event)
    {
        // Do something on pre update.
    }
}
```

Other Methods are also available which can be use like this:

```
<doctrine-mapping>
    <entity name="MyProject\Entity\User">
         <entity-listeners>
            <entity-listener class="UserListener">
                <lifecycle-callback type="preFlush"      method="preFlushHandler"/>
                <lifecycle-callback type="postLoad"      method="postLoadHandler"/>

                <lifecycle-callback type="postPersist"   method="postPersistHandler"/>
                <lifecycle-callback type="prePersist"    method="prePersistHandler"/>

                <lifecycle-callback type="postUpdate"    method="postUpdateHandler"/>
                <lifecycle-callback type="preUpdate"     method="preUpdateHandler"/>

                <lifecycle-callback type="postRemove"    method="postRemoveHandler"/>
                <lifecycle-callback type="preRemove"     method="preRemoveHandler"/>
            </entity-listener>
        </entity-listeners>
        <!-- .... -->
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

More Details are [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners)

Another Way to do it is Write Even Listeners Like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class MyEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            Events::postUpdate,
        );
    }

    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();

        // perhaps you only want to act on some "Product" entity
        if ($entity instanceof Product) {
            // do something with the Product
        }
    }
```

The only disadvantage is:

> Lifecycle events are triggered for all entities. It is the
>   responsibility of the listeners and subscribers to check if the entity
>   is of a type it wants to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need yo create a custom repository. Take a look at this post: [How exactly do I create a custom EntityManager in Symfony2/Doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884900/how-exactly-do-i-create-a-custom-entitymanager-in-symfony2-doctrine)