# How exactly do I create a custom EntityManager in Symfony2/Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

New guy at Symfony/Doctrine. So kindly guide me.

Requirement: To create a custom EntityManager which would override some of the methods like remove (instead of remove, i want to perform an update and modify a parameter like isValid in my class, so that the records are never deleted) and a find ( find a record which has a non zero isValid ) etc and use it instead of Doctrine's EntityManager.

I started reading through this thread:
[Is there a way to specify Doctrine2 Entitymanager implementation class in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138962/is-there-a-way-to-specify-doctrine2-entitymanager-implementation-class-in-symfon) and found the answer by user2563451 to be not so straightforward. I got lost when he talks about not to follow certain approaches (again no location of the files to be modified).

I have looked at the EntityManager.php and it specifically tells not to use extend the EntityManager class. Rather it asks to extend the EntityManagerDecorator. On looking at the EntityManagerDecorator, there are no methods available inside it (like create, persist, etc which I found in EntityManager) Does it mean I need to create new methods for each and every single Entity Manager functionality ?

Since there is no clear defined way to get this done, I am confused to get this thing started. Also Doctrine cookbook is of little use to me as it does not have any information to achieve this.

So any help regarding the extending of EntityManagerDecorator or EntityManager is appreciated.

Best if you can provide me step by step directions to achieve the same.

Thanks !

Edit 1: my requirement is to use my custom EntityManager instead of Doctrine's EntityManager (EM) and modify those 'remove' and 'find' methods as per my requirements. I am not sure whether I need to reuse the functionality provided by Doctrine's EM or write from scratch.

Comment: If all you want to do is add an `isValid` type field there is a `softdelete` filter that uses a `deletedAt` field that when the filter is enabled and the `deletedAt` has a date then the records do not show up. It also allows you to set a time in the future when a record will become "deleted". You may still want to do your own but it could save you a fair bit of time - https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md

Comment: Thanks for recommending, but I prefer not to use the custom Doctrine extensions at this point of time (extra overhead of maintaining them). I want to limit myself to the usage of standard Doctrine API's and methods.

Comment: Fair enough. Although the benefit of using a well used package is that there are multiple people keeping it up to date rather than having to rely on yourself to keep everything in sync with Doctrine itself. Also it does use the standard API and methods, where as your approach would be the road less travelled.. so to speak.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you may be confusing a Manager with a Repository.

An EntityManager is really nothing more than a Service you use to manage that specific or a collection of entities.

A repository extends `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` and is what tells Doctrine how to store your entity in the database.

You can use the combination of these two to achieve what you want.

For example.  Let's take our entity Foo

```
class Foo
{
    //...other properties

    protected $isValid;

    //...Getters and setters
}
```

We then have a manager for Foo.

```
class FooManager
{
    protected $class;
    protected $orm;
    protected $repo;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $orm , $class)
    {
        $this->orm = $orm;
        $this->repo = $orm->getRepository($class);

        $metaData = $orm->getClassMetadata($class);
        $this->class = $metaData->getName();
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $class = $this->getClass();
        $foo = new $class;

        return $foo;
    }

    public function findBy(array $criteria)
    {
        return $this->repo->findOneBy($criteria);
    }

    public function refreshFoo(Foo $foo)
    {
        $this->orm->refresh($foo);
    }

    public function updateFoo(Foo $foo, $flush = true)
    {   
        $this->orm->persist($foo);
        if($flush)
        {
            $this->orm->flush();
        }
    }

    public function getClass()
    {
        return $this->class;
    }
}
```

We have some basic functions for Creating and Updating our object.  And now if you wanted to "remove" it without actually deleting it, you can add the following function in the Manager.

```
public function remove(Foo $foo)
{
    $foo->setIsValid(false);
    return $this->update($foo);
}
```

This way, we update the `isValid` fields to false and persist it to the database.  And you'd use this like any service inside your controller.

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function someAction()
    {
        $fooManager = $this->get('my_foo_manager');
        $newFoo = $fooManager->create();

        //...
        $fooManager->remove($newFoo);
    }
}
```

So now we've got the remove part.

Next, we only want to find entities that `isValid` set to TRUE.

Honestly, the way I'd handle this is not even modify the find and instead in your controller

```
if(!$foo->getIsValid())
{
    //Throw some kind of error.  Or redirect to an error page.
}
```

But if you want to do it the other way.  You can just make a repo.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
class FooRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function find($id, $lockMode = LockMode::NONE, $lockVersion = null)
    {
        //Some custom doctrine query.
    }
}
```

We override EntityRepository's native find() function with our own.

Finally we get all of this registered in the right places.  For the manager you've got to make a service.

```
services:
    my_foo_manager:
        class: AppBundle\Manager\FooManager
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" , 'AppBundle\Entity\Foo']
```

And for the repository, you must specify the `repositoryClass` in the ORM definition of your entity.

```
AppBundle\Entity\Foo:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Entity\FooRepository
    table: foos
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: {strategy: AUTO}
            options: {unsigned: true}
    fields:
        isValid:
            type: boolean
```

Knowing all of this you can now do some pretty cool things with Entities.  I hope this helped.  Good luck!

Comment: This approach has got me thinking on how to get started, but i need to use my EntityManager instead of Doctrine's Entity Manager. 

So that when am using $this->em, it has to use my EntityManager instead of Doctrine's.

I should have specified the question better. I update the same in first post.

Comment: @VKB That's the point of registering the `repositoryClass: AppBundle\Entity\FooRepository` And I forgot to mention at the top of my manager I have 3 properties.  One in `protected $repo` set in the constructor `$this->repo = $orm->getRepository($class);` and uses the repository you registered in your ORM declaration.  So if you have some custom function you'll just use `$this->repo->myCustomFunction()`  Take a look at my `findBy()` function in the FooManager and you'll see this in action.

Comment: This FooRepository is now part of the entity and i need to create a new repository for every new class I use (correct me if I am wrong). 

Then having it as an extended EntityManager helps me to avoid the maintenance of extra classes.

Comment: @VKB Not every entity requires you make a Repo or manager.  For the most part, the native repo that all entities already inherit should cover you.  And the separation of tasks these managers, entities, and repos afford you means most files should be more than 100 lines of code.  As I said in my answer.  You really shouldn't be selecting based on `isValid` (maybe for analytics) but not in every day use.  You instead in your controller should be checking if `isValid` is true or not and then displaying a proper error or doing a polite redirect.

Comment: If you have a chance check out FOSUserBundle https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle  and see how they use managers and repos.  It's really where I learned a lot of this from.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your use cases, you should instead use [Doctrine Lifecycle Callbacks](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks) for the remove case and simple overide the find method in your entity repository.

Comment: Am not sure how that would work in my case, as these are Pre/Post Persist/ Update/Remove tasks. In my case the 'remove' event will happen regardless of what happens before or after the lifecycle callbacks.  ---> which is what I dont want. Also I do not currently have an Entity Repository.